# Django channels or Signals?

Tags: django, signals, channel

Channels or signals for user notification.

Im currently working on creating this online booking django app. I was quite new on django and im wondering what should i use to notify certain users that a new booking has been made. The user will be notified once he/she already logged-in. Do i use channels or signals?

Comment: signals are not related to notifications. Signals are just to trigger some actions before/after some changes in models , like pre_save, post_save etc. channels on the other hand are used to create a websocket that retains a connection with client and used for 2 way communication

Comment: It does not seem like you know what both Channels and Signals / Receivers do and should read more about both of them. They are extremely different and solve different problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both. You can create a web socket using Django channels for a duplex communication between the client and the server. You should then create a signal to listen to a new booking created event.

Every time a new booking is created, the signal will get trigerred and send the data via the web socket to the client.

Comment: Thanks Vipin! Do you have any sample codes that I can use to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Within the connect method of the consumer class named "Reload", we define a global variable named "id". The value of the variable is the instance of the consumer websocket connection. We define a django signal outside the class "custom_signal" that is triggered when a Person object is created and sends a message through the websocket using id variable.

```
class Reload(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
      # accept connection
      self.accept()
      
    
      global id # create a global variable so that its accessible outside of the class
      id = self # assign the instance of the consumer class to the global variable
    
    def disconnect(self, close_code):
      pass
    
    # receive message from websocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
      text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
      print(text_data_json)
      self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message':'Its working'}))

# django signal that runs custom_signal function when a Person object is created
@receiver(signal=post_save, sender=Person) 
def custom_signal(**kwargs):
   
    # send a message through the websocket connection through the global variable
    id.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message':'updated'}))
```

Comment: Put the code directly in your answer, instead of putting a screenshot of it.

Comment: Wouldnt it be more "djangonic" to not share a global variable but rather send a message via the get_channel_layer() to the consumer, as described here https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers